# Creating databases at runtime with Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, schema

Is it possible to use Hibernate to, at runtime, create a new database (using the annotations of the model objects as schema, **or** from a normal schema file we define), and then get a connection to that database so that it can be used?

What we would like to do is, when a certain action happens (for instance a new user is created), we create a new databse for that user (from the defined annotations or simply a static schema), and then have a handle to that database so the user can write to it.

*The user thing is simply for illustrating the concept...*

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At a high-level, what you would do to accomplish something like this is:

1. When the trigger event happens, execute the DDL to create a new database through a JDBC connection - probably makes the most sense for this schema to be generated by `hbm2ddl` at build-time.
2. Construct a new `DataSource` for this database, and a new `SessionFactory` from the `DataSource`
3. This `SessionFactory` should then be injected into (or looked up by) the data-access layer of your application, to find the appropriate `SessionFactory` for the User.

In short, the answer is to construct `SessionFactory` instances dynamically for each connection/database and make sure that your data-access layer knows how to find the appropriate `SessionFactory` for the criteria.

Comment: This seems like the most logical solution. Is this scalable though? How many session factories (and their datasources) can be held by the single application?

Comment: I have no idea but if you do some benchmarking and tests I'd love to see the results :)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with matt b, but are you sure it's a good idea to do such a thing?

I guess you have different customers and want to store each one's data in a separate database (or something like that).
Why not storing all customers data in the same database, and filter these data by the customer id?

Comment: As I said in the question, the customer example I gave was just that, an example. It's not the way we are going to use it, but the principles are the same. Also, we are simply researching different approaches at the moment. Another one we are looking at is to have seperation by using a key (such as customer id).

Comment: The reason I'm looking up this question personally is due to very strict security terms by my client that requires the seperate DB approach. It's required their data be stored in the same country as their organisation, and so we need to be able to server multiple databases.

Answer (score 1):

I've followed a discussion in my company some times ago and they were talking about spring support for doing that.

Some things that could interest you:
http://blog.springsource.com/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/aop/target/HotSwappableTargetSource.html

AbstractRoutingDataSource seems to be interesting for your case. Someone also said that this perhaps disable the 2nd hibernate cache, to confirm...

Answer (score 1):

I come back a little late but if you'r planning to build a multi tenancy SAAS application, as you said, you could also use a separation by key like customer id.

In hibernate, the filters help you to do that...

See:
http://www.lunatech-research.com/archives/2011/03/04/play-framework-writing-multitenancy-application-hibernate-filters

It's a link for play framework but it uses hibernate so you could do almost the same with classic Java EE stuff...

Comment: @Sebastian Lorber - Jip, that is what we have implemented. It's called discriminator based multi-tenancy.